# Nested joins in MS SQL, not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

This is the table structure (the relevant bits):

[image: Basic table structure]

I'm trying to find the contactLog entries that match the declarations on clientID and the date of the declaration (within 8 hours actually). Here's what I came up with:

```
SELECT
D.ClientID
D.DeclarationID   
CL.ContactDescription,
CL.ContactDate,

FROM Declarations D

INNER JOIN  (Contacts C
         INNER JOIN (PartialContacts PC
             INNER JOIN ContactLogs CL
                ON PC.ContactPartID = CL.ContactPartID )
            on PC.ContactID = C.ContactID
     )  
    ON C.ClientID = D.ClientID AND DATEDIFF(hour, D.DeclarationDate, CL.ContactDate) < 8
```

However, the join is not functioning properly, because I get non matching dates back for the  CL.ContactDate and it's clear that it's just return every row in CL for that patient ID. I think... I'm not really sure what is going wrong.

[image]

Comment: I'm missing table `Declarations` and how it is related to `Clients` in your model.

Comment: Where did `PL` come from? Should it be `CL`? Also, are you only wanting contacts that come within 8 hours *after* the declaration? `DATEDIFF` is perfectly capable of returning negative values if the first date is greater than the second, and all negative values are < 8.

Comment: Tim: Declarations is right there in the model, below the others, and the relation is ClientID.
Damien: PL = PC, typo (this is not the actual query, for security's sake.

Comment: Damien, that's it, negative values for datedif. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Damien:

I did not specify a lower limit for datediff, so the matching did not work properly. Apperently, the joins are just fine:

```
SELECT
D.ClientID
D.DeclarationID   
CL.ContactDescription,
CL.ContactDate,

FROM Declarations D

INNER JOIN  (Contacts C
         INNER JOIN (PartialContacts PC
             INNER JOIN ContactLogs CL
                ON PC.ContactPartID = CL.ContactPartID )
            on PC.ContactID = C.ContactID
     )  
    ON C.ClientID = D.ClientID AND DATEDIFF(hour, D.DeclarationDate, CL.ContactDate) < 8 DATEDIFF(hour, D.DeclarationDate, CL.ContactDate) > 0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
D.ClientID
D.DeclarationID   
CL.ContactDescription,
CL.ContactDate
FROM Declarations D
INNER JOIN Clients CL ON D.ClientID=CL.ClientID
INNER JOIN  Contacts CO ON CL.ClientID=CO.ClientID
INNER JOIN PartialContact PC ON PC.ContactID=CO.ContactID
INNER JOIN ContactLog CL ON CL.ContactPartID=PC.ContactPartID
WHERE DATEDIFF(hour, D.DeclarationDate, CL.ContactDate) BETWEEN 0 AND 8
```